# Duvida Recebimento de parametros (WebService Soap)

Tags: java, web-service, soap

Galera, estou com duvida no seguinte cenário:

Tenho essa classe, ela é um webservice (contem o método @WebService):

```
@WebService(name = "l", targetNamespace = "o")
    public abstract interface Service {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Cancelar")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "Cancelar", targetNamespace = "http://www.x.com.br/y/w", className = "br.com.x.y.w.CancelarRequest")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "CancelarResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.x.com.br/y/w", className = "br.com.x.y.w.CancelarResponse")
    public abstract void Cancelar(
            @WebParam(name = "k", targetNamespace = "http://www.x.com.br/y/w", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT) Holder<String> paramHolder,
            @WebParam(name = "Result", targetNamespace = "http://www.x.com.br/y/w", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<ResultType> paramHolder1);
    }
```

Minha duvida é: se essa classe é um webservice porque defini-la como "abstract interface", alias, - oque acontece quando defino uma classe usando "abstract interface". Até hoje só criei classes que usam um ou outro.

Observe que essa classe é a interface remota, ela define os serviços remotos (@Method), porem não os implementa, toda a implementação parece estar na classe ServiceImpl:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service     
    @Override
    public void Cancelar(
            Holder<String> k,
            Holder<ResultType> result) {

        CancelarP p = new CancelarP(ctx, k.value);
        CancelarResponseType execute = p.execute();
        ResultType resultType = execute.getResult();
        result.value = resultType;
    }
```

Na classe ServiceImpl, se quando eu dou um @Override perco a implementação da classe pai, como farei os Marshall do xml recebido via Soap?. Não estou conseguindo compreender como essas classes estão trabalhando em conjunto.

Espero ter conseguido ser claro na elaboração da pergunta, desde ja agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá.
Quando vc dá um @Override em `Cancelar()`você não está perdendo a implementação da interface, justamente por não haver nenhuma, sendo ela uma interface.

O que pode ter te levado a acreditar nisso são as anotações que o criador da interface colocou nos parametros do método.

Para a primeira pergunta, irei traduzir uma resposta a uma pergunta identica feita no SO. 
Eu sinceramente nunca usei nada que implementasse a anotação `@WebService`então só posso descrever a parte técnica.

Não há necessidade de colocar `abstract`em uma interface, por ela já ser abstrata, e adicionando-o não muda em nada.

```
public abstract interface Interface {
       \___.__/
           |
           '----> Não é necessário...

public void interfacing();
public abstract boolean interfacing(boolean really);
       \___.__/
           |
           '----> nem aqui.
}
```

> Há alguma mudança na implementação de uma p/ outra?

Não, exatamente a mesma coisa. Os métodos continuarão a ser implementados de forma concreta em suas classes filha.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface)

Edição: Uma coisa que esqueci de comentar. As anotações dos métodos provavelmente estão ali para que elas sejam manipuladas da forma correta por algum framework. E como estão na interface, não haverá nenhum mal em não coloca-las na classe `impl`.